# Is this posting on lower temperature nuclear thermal disassociation of n2o4 and nh3 prior art?

Tags: prior-art-request

In reference to the patent: [US20130199155](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130199155)

is this prior art.

http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=13055.msg378028#msg378028
toby